# Bootstrap spinner in a table with sticky header not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a Razor Page application with a table display on the index page. The table has a sticky header with a spinner on one of the columns. When the table is scrolled vertically, the text in the column goes under the table header(which is sticky), but the spinner stays on top of the table header.
[image]

[image]

My html code is

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<style>
    th.sticky {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
</style>

<table class="table">
    <thead class="table-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center sticky border-0">#</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center sticky border-0">First</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center sticky border-0">Last</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center sticky border-0">Handle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mdo <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" id="spinner" role="status"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to hide the spinner the same way as the text underneath the table header?

Comment: Have you tried adding a z-index to your sticky header?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to keep the spinner on top of the sticky header while scrolling. To achieve this, you can use the position: sticky property for the spinner column as well. Here's the modified code snippet:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<style>
    th.sticky {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
    .spinner-column {
        position: sticky;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #f8f9fa;
        left: 0;
        width: 56px; /* Adjust this width according to your needs */
    }
</style>

<table class="table">
    <thead class="table-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center sticky border-0">#</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center sticky border-0">First</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center sticky border-0">Last</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center sticky border-0 spinner-column">
                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" id="spinner" role="status"></span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- ... Rest of your table content ... -->
</table>
```